# Cannot get rid of "Changes to be committed" message even after commit/push

Tags: git

I'm keep getting `Changes to be committed` message from `git status` command even after committed and pushed to origin. I can see the changes on origin/master. How can I get rid of this message?

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:  foo.php

$ git commit -m 'message' foo.php
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing added to commit
```

EDIT

Actually, foo.php was a different name say foo-org.php before and I renamed it with:

```
git mv foo-org.php foo.php
```

I run git add foo.php then git commit -m 'renamed' foo.php then git push orign master.
I can see the file on online repo (origin/master) is up to date, so I have no idea why it is still saying "Changes to be committed".

Comment: You must add your changed file with `git add`. Then you can commit this change. I recommend you to take a look at this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide).

Comment: I did git add before commit. The file is on master already as mentioned in my post. I tried to add again just in case, but nothing happened.

Comment: you don't "get rid of a message" because you don't like it. You read the message, understand that `foo.php` is modified and not committed, reason on why that is the case, and take the appropriate course of action. If you run `, could you post the entire commands you run?

Comment: It seems you didn't understand quite well how Git works. Take your time and read the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). You will see your question from a different angle after that.

Comment: I run 'git status' 'git add' 'git commit -m' 'git push origin'. Those commands have been working OK till I get this situation today. I run those commands quite few times on foo.php already, but 'git status' still shows the Changes to be committed' message.

Comment: What does `git diff foo.php` tell you ?

Comment: Do you have a pre-commit hook installed? If so, what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the remote master branch is up-to-date, try and reset your local branch to it:

```
git fetch
git switch -C master origin/master
```

Or, if you are already locally on `master`:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Check then if the `git status` still report a non-empty index.